# Observable.timer saving state

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using rxjava and rxandroid. In my presenter i have used

```
Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And I would like to save time on screen orientation change. For example timer starts and after 3 seconds user is changing screen orientation, and timer starts again but from 0 for 10 seconds, but it needs to run for 7 remaining seconds.

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you orientate your device, it recall `onCreate()` method of your activity and redraw your views. For this you can create a helper fragment and put your operations in that fragment. Put this line `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreate()` method. Then, do your operations on`AsyncTask`. If you wand display each second of timer in your screen, then call `onProgressUpdate()` method of your `AsyncTask` class. Then, create an interface, with`Progress` callback and put this callback in `onProgressUpdate()` method. Then you can handle this operations via implementing that interface which you created in your fragment. I have simple repository in github which can help you. [Enjoy](https://github.com/JavadBadirkhanli/orientation-mode). This article also can help you: [Enjoy](http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/).

Comment: I dont think so using rxjava and later use async task as a good solution. Maybe can I solve my problem with rxjava cache function?

Comment: Of course you can, i didn't tested your task, but i have an idea. Put that Observable method in one method, and create other method which returns you time(3 seconds or smth). Create fragment in your activity, and check if it's null in onCreate method, if(fragment==null)  {fragment = new Fragment} else { fragment.getTime()} .

Comment: it's not RxJava cache function, it's my cache function )))